# wrong site description when post new status on LinkedIn

Tags: share, linkedin-api

I have a strange problem, in my website I use HibrydAuth to share status with Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

All runs fine but I have a wrong description for the site in the LinkedIn page. An image could explain better than a lot of words, but I can't post images so, please, try to use a bit of imagination: this is a shared post from my web site

---

**link to the website page**

text shared from the website page

---

**Here I have the link to my web site**

here I would have the description of the web site

but I have the footer line of the web site

---

So my question is: how or where I can set the right description?
I checked in the LinkedIn account without result and the HibrydAuth library don't gives me options to set it.

Thank you for your help

Paolo